# SF book about one or more mysterious, pyramid-shaped artefacts that appear at the edge of Earth's solar system

Tags: story-identification, books, space

I've been looking for this book for decades. :) I read it in the mid 90s which makes me think it was probably written around that time or in the 80s. It could be part of a series or a standalone book.

What I remember is that there are white artefacts appearing at the edge of our solar system which turn out to be pyramids (I think, not 100% sure if it was just one or multiple pyramids) and humans are trying to figure out what it is. Whether it's an alien spaceship, whether it contains life, friendly or evil aliens, etc. So the main part of the story is about the astronauts traveling there to find out (I think).

In the end, the pyramid(s) was some kind of record of all memories and knowledge on Earth and the book specifically mentioned the word 'googol' for the amount of records it contained.

Trying to google the word googol has gotten me nowhere, but perhaps someone can help. Thank you!

Comment: There's the tetrahedral Kupier anomaly in these books https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Destiny%27s_Children

Comment: Take a look at ["Wolfbane"](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/1875941.Wolfbane) by C.M. Kornbluth and Frederik Pohl, there are some misterius pyramids, that stole our planet.